# Self registered factory using reflection in c#

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, enums, factory

I would like some feedback on the implementation of the following factory:

```
public enum DietType {Carnivore, Herbivore, Omnivore};

[AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class DietTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DietType dietType { get; private set; }

    public DietTypeAttribute(DietType dietType)
    {
        this.dietType = dietType;
    }
}

public abstract class Diet { }

[DietTypeAttribute(DietType.Carnivore)]
public class Carnivore : Diet
{
}

[DietTypeAttribute(DietType.Herbivore)]
public class Herbivore : Diet
{
}

abstract class AbstractFactory<T> where T : class
{
    protected Dictionary<Enum, Type> types;

    protected AbstractFactory()
    {
    }

    public T CreateInstance(Enum id, params object[] param)
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(types[id], param);
    }
}

class DietFactory : AbstractFactory<Diet>
{
    public DietFactory()
    {
        types = (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                 from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                 let attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DietTypeAttribute), true)
                 where (attributes.Any()) && (typeof(Diet).IsAssignableFrom(type)) && (type.IsClass)
                 select
                 new
                 {
                     dietEnum = (Enum)((DietTypeAttribute)attributes.First()).dietType,
                     dietType = type
                 }).ToDictionary(x => x.dietEnum, x => x.dietType);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AbstractFactory<Diet> factory = new DietFactory();
        Diet diet = factory.CreateInstance(DietType.Carnivore);
    }
```

The main idea is to self register the classes with the use of enums instead of strings. I'm struggling to find a way to make the registration "generic", so i can avoid to specifying the attribute class on the LINQ query.

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: Why using `enums`? Having a `Factory` with `CreateInstance<TEntity>` is not sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this..

```
public enum DietType {Carnivore, Herbivore, Omnivore};

public class FactoryAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Object Something { get; protected set; }
}

[AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class DietTypeAttribute : FactoryAttribute
{
    public DietTypeAttribute(DietType dietType)
    {
        this.Something = dietType;
    }
}

public abstract class Diet { }

[DietTypeAttribute(DietType.Carnivore)]
public class Carnivore : Diet
{
}

[DietTypeAttribute(DietType.Herbivore)]
public class Herbivore : Diet
{
}

abstract class AbstractFactory<T> where T : class
{
    protected Dictionary<Enum, Type> types;

    protected AbstractFactory()
    {
    }

    protected void Register<TEnumType, TSubType>()
        where TEnumType: FactoryAttribute
    {

        types = (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                 from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                 let attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TEnumType), true)
                 where (attributes.Any()) && (typeof(TSubType).IsAssignableFrom(type)) && (type.IsClass)
                 select
                 new
                 {
                     dietEnum = (Enum)((TEnumType)attributes.First()).Something,
                     dietType = type
                 }).ToDictionary(x => x.dietEnum, x => x.dietType);
    }

    public T CreateInstance(Enum id, params object[] param)
    {   
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(types[id], param);
    }
}

class DietFactory : AbstractFactory<Diet>
{
    public DietFactory()
    {
        Register<DietTypeAttribute, Diet>(); 
    }
}
```

And testing...

```
void Main()
{
    AbstractFactory<Diet> factory = new DietFactory();
    Diet diet = factory.CreateInstance(DietType.Carnivore);
    //diet is a 'Carnivore'
    diet = factory.CreateInstance(DietType.Herbivore);
    //diet is a 'Herbivore'
}
```

**Edit: 
You don't actually need the template types for this**

```
abstract class AbstractFactory<T> where T : class
{
    protected Dictionary<Enum, Type> types;

    protected AbstractFactory()
    {
        types = (from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                 from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                 let attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FactoryAttribute), true)
                 where (attributes.Any()) && (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type)) && (type.IsClass)
                 select
                 new
                 {
                     dietEnum = (Enum)((FactoryAttribute)attributes.First()).Something,
                     dietType = type
                 }).ToDictionary(x => x.dietEnum, x => x.dietType);
    }

    public T CreateInstance(Enum id, params object[] param)
    {   
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(types[id], param);
    }
}
```

And your factory is simply:

```
class DietFactory : AbstractFactory<Diet>
{
    public DietFactory()
    {
    }
}
```